# How to transform many variables (characters) to the dmy format using `dmy` function?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, date, lubridate

Let's say I have this df (but so much bigger)

```
library(lubridate)


df = data.frame(id=1:5,date1 = c("2023/01/02","2023/08/03","2023/09/09","2023/11/05","2023/04/03"),
                date2 = c("2023/02/02","2023/09/03","2023/10/09","2023/12/05","2023/05/03"))
```

I tried using `lapply` with `dmy` function of `lubridate` library but it didn't work i don't know why.

```
dd = colnames(df[,-1])

df[dd] = lapply(df[dd],dmy)
```

and the output is

```
Warning messages:
1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
2: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Comment: You should show us what you tried, and the result it gave.

Comment: I added what I did and the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `ymd` rather than `dmy`, since your date strings are in the format of `%Y/%m/%d`

```
> df %>%
+     mutate_if(is.character, ymd)
  id      date1      date2
1  1 2023-01-02 2023-02-02
2  2 2023-08-03 2023-09-03
3  3 2023-09-09 2023-10-09
4  4 2023-11-05 2023-12-05
5  5 2023-04-03 2023-05-03
```

If you really want the dates presented in the `dmy` format, you can try

```
> df %>%
+     mutate_if(is.character, ~ format(ymd(.x), "%d/%m/%Y"))
  id      date1      date2
1  1 02/01/2023 02/02/2023
2  2 03/08/2023 03/09/2023
3  3 09/09/2023 09/10/2023
4  4 05/11/2023 05/12/2023
5  5 03/04/2023 03/05/2023
```